# What is the difference between starting a command with an ! and starting a command with % in Google Colab? !<command> or %<command>

Tags: python-3.x, shell, google-colaboratory

If I open a Python 3 notebook in Google Colab and I run:

```
!pwd
!cd ..
!pwd
```

I get:

```
/content
/content
```

Whereas running:

```
!pwd
%cd ..
!pwd
```

Results in:

```
/content
/
/
```

What's the difference between the execution of `!some command` and `%some command`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bang `!` open a new process before calling that command.

So, a `!cd` won't change your current process. After it has run, you return back to where you were.

`%cd` is a magic (there are a few others) that do what you want.

So, normally you will use `!` for most of your linux commands. Except a few magics that you will use occationally e.g. `%cd`, `%env`